# xmlhttprequest not being posted to php file

Tags: javascript, php, apache, xmlhttprequest, http-post

I am trying to make a post request through javascript to a locally hosted php file but it seems the php file is either not receiving the data or not displaying.
I tried all sorts of ways to print with vardump print_r $_post $_request raw_http_data but nothing seems to work.

what is wrong with the code?
is the url a problem?

This is the javascript file:

```
const rightswipe = (n) =>{
    var foo = "me";
    var bar = "ft";
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() 
    {
        if(this.readyState === 4) 
        {
            if(this.status==200 || this.status==201)
            {
                //let newData = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                //console.log(newData);
            }
            else{
                alert("invalid link");
            }
        }
    });
    xhr.open("POST", "like.php" , true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.send("to_user="+foo+"&from_user="+bar);

};
```

like.php is a file in the same folder:

```
if (array_key_exists('foo', $_POST) && array_key_exists('bar', $_POST)) {
    
        $foo = $_POST['foo'];
        $bar = ($_POST['bar']);
        // do stuff with params
    
        echo 'Yes, it works!';
    
    } else {
        echo 'Invalid parameters!';
    }
```

also the $_post and $_request are empty;
and var_dump($_server["REQUEST_METHOD"]) returns "GET"
and am locally hosting this site with xampp ie apache and mysql

Comment: Have you checked the request and response in the browser developer tools network panel?

Comment: perhaps `rightswipe` is never called

Comment: @JaromandaX rightswipe also contains other css alterations which i have not included here since they were irrelevant. these css alterations are taking place thus i can assure you that rightswipe IS being called.

Comment: @DamianDziaduch i checked it in the network section, the request method is showing POST and does not give out any sort of error

Comment: Typo: `xhr.send("to_user="+foo+"&from_user="+bar);` your keys are called `to_user` and `from_user` not `foo` and `bar` (which are what you are looking for: `$foo = $_POST['foo'];`)

Answer (score 0):

I have set up a test and your code works fine. There is just one problem that I can see and that is you post "to_user" and "from_user" parameters but in your PHP you check for "foo" and "bar" keys. Therefore in my test I get "Invalid parameters!" returned as expected.

Note: Currently your PHP is returning text so if you were to uncomment the JSON.parse line you would likely get a JavaScript error. Make sure to json_encode your response in PHP.

I am not sure what your test that showed the request method was "GET" but suspect it was not a valid test as you clearly send a POST request.

**UPDATE following discussion below:**

I installed the same XAMPP version mentioned on Windows 10 and setup the basic files and still cannot replicate the problem.

C:\xampp\htdocs\rightswipe.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

  <script src="rightswipe.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

C:\xampp\htdocs\rightswipe.js

```
const rightswipe = (n) =>{
    var foo = "me";
    var bar = "ft";
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() 
    {
        if(this.readyState === 4) 
        {
            if(this.status==200 || this.status==201)
            {
                let newData = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                console.log(newData);
            }
            else{
                alert("invalid link");
            }
        }
    });
    xhr.open("POST", "like.php" , true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.send("to_user="+foo+"&from_user="+bar);

};
```

C:\xampp\htdocs\like.php

```
<?php
if (array_key_exists('to_user', $_POST) && array_key_exists('from_user', $_POST)) {
    
        $foo = $_POST['to_user'];
        $bar = ($_POST['from_user']);
        // do stuff with params
    
        echo json_encode('Yes, it works!');
    
    } else {
        echo json_encode('Invalid parameters!');
    }
```

Went to http://localhost/rightswipe.html in Chrome and opened developer tools (F12)

In the console tab I entered `rightswipe(1);` and saw the console log message 'Yes, it works!'

Went to network tab to check request and response:
[image: Screenshot of the network tab Headers to show form data]

Everything working as expected.

Comment: thank you @mark. i fixed this to from_user and to_user but it still doesnt work; it still gives  "Invalid parameters!" . also, vardump $_POST and $_REQUEST are empty.

Comment: That tells me that something else is going on with your code that we cannot see here because, as I said, I set up a test with the code provided and it works fine once I corrected the couple of issues mentioned. Is there more code in like.php that we are not seeing? Where are you putting vardump and how are you confirming they are empty?

Comment: no, this is all like.php contains as of now. i temporily put vardump to confim $_post is empty. also, when i tried to make a form, $_post showed results

Comment: When you test this, are you clicking a button or some other user action on the HTML or do you call the rightswipe function directly? If you are using a click or such then please try calling the function directly: open Developer Tools and in the console tab enter `rightswipe(1);`. In the network tab find the request and check the full url called is correct. Check the request payload to ensure it has sent to_user and from_user. You already confirmed it was sending with POST. Finally look at the response and share the response payload. Before doing this remove any dumps from the PHP code.

Comment: i am clicking a button to call rightswipe. i tried calling it through right swipe like you said but it still doesnt work. also, i noticed that in the network panel of the page from where i am sending the request, its type is shown as xhr and request method as post. but on the receiving page, the type is document and request method is get. i also changed the enable_post_data_reading from off to on in php.ini but it did not help.

Comment: What you are describing shouldn't be possible, the browser cannot send a POST request but the server treats it as a GET unless a there is some proxy request going on in the middle but as you are locally testing with xampp I do not think there should be a problem. In my last comment I asked you to check, on the network tab, for the request and response payloads and confirm you can see your post data being sent and confirm what the response in developer tools is. At this stage I would also suggest you set up a completely separate test site with only the bare minimum code from your question.

Comment: Another thought: Do you have a htaccess file that could be redirecting the request?

Comment: im sorry i forgot to mention it in my last comment, i checked the request payload, it coorectly shows the exact data that i am trying to send. the response payload is empty as of now but if i put a vardump($_post) in the php file then it shows array(0) { } in the response payload. also, i tried making new test files in a different folder just to post data like u said, but im still facing the same problem.

Comment: i am new to this so i do not understand the exact purpose of htaccess rn and there is no such file in my folder. but there is one htaccess php file in the xampp folder.

Comment: I think the only thing I can do now is to try and replicate your environment if possible, i.e. install xampp myself and test with that. Please could you tell me your Operating System and what version of xampp you installed and if you modified any of the configuration in any way.

Comment: i use windows 10 XAMPP-windows-x64-7.4.11-0-VC15. i have not modified anything

Comment: I have set up the test on Windows 10 with the same XAMPP as you (fresh installation) and I'm afraid I do not get the problem. Please see the edited answer above as I have added more details about the setup and test. That htacess php file you mentioned is in the php\pear\File directory and is a class to manipulate htaccess files so it is irrelevant. As you don't have any other htaccess files you don't need to worry about that. I'm sorry, I do not have any other ideas to help you. Please check the code I have given above and see if you can set up the exact same test as I did.